# Check Portrait or Landscape in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm developing a WP/ camera app that shows the picture that have been taken. Is there a way to somehow know how your currently holding your camera so that the image preview will display the picture as portrait or landscape?

Answer (score 5):

Have a read of [How to Handle Orientation Changes in WP7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769553%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

On `PhoneApplicationFrame` you have Orientation property

Answer (score 0):

Just replace or add the below codes to PhoneApplicationFrame.....

```
SupportedOrientations=”PortraitOrLandscape”
```